# Creating a "Jump Pad" in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been going through the internet searching for a way to make me automatically jump when I walk/jump over/onto an object like a cylinder that has been minimized. All I find is tutorials on how to make an object pass through another object that is standing still. What I'm basically asking for is help with OnTriggerEnter and how to actually code the cylinder to make me automatically jump when I walk/jump over/onto it. I've tried a few things out but none seem to be working.

Comment: You want a thing to throw you up when you enter the thing's area?

Comment: Basically, yes. I should be able to adjust the force it pushes me up.

Comment: Something like addForce? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html

Comment: If you know how to detect collisions using Triggers and how to apply a force to a rigidbody, it should be a piece of cake to do what you want. Please, provide the code you have tried so far, and explain "what does not work"

Comment: I do apologise Hellium, but I just started working with c# yesterday. I have no idea how to make a code that detects collision, but I have seen tutorials on it and it doesn't help because I have no idea what to do after that. I apologise for my lack of knowledge in this matter.

Comment: @Enigma check out the official site https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials
You will find more than enough to start with and it starts with the absolut basics.

Comment: @Zibelas I appriciate the website link, but since this is a school project I'll be needing to be finished with my assignment and won't have the time to learn the basics. I know enough to make the idea I've got in my head. All I really need is this code

Comment: @Enigma If you have one hour to cut a tree, 50min of sharpening the tools are not wasted time

Comment: @Zibelas I know the "basics" all the tools and stuff, settings and all that. I've made my "map" and I've made a character, mountains, objects, all that. I know the "basics" all I really need is the advanced stuff that won't find it's path to me for some reason. And I've looked into addforce but isn't that just a code to make your character able to jump? I might be wrong though

Comment: If you don't have time to look at tutorials that explain how to do what you want, then you shouldn't be asking questions on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow isn't where you come to ask people to do your homework for you. You need to make a real attempt at solving your problem, do research, explain what your issue with your code is, and show your work by providing a [MCVE].

Comment: Since I have explained my issue, and I've been through the website and I've even asked the same question there, I think I'm qualified  to ask a question here, don't you?

Comment: I just read your comments under the answer below and I think you need to watch Unity tutorials. You are asking the most basic Unity questions and can't even implement what's in the answer. Please go to Unity's website and learn basic Unity before making your own game.

Comment: If you did read my comment you'd know that I also started yesterday. Not to mention this isn't a "game" it's just a school assignment. I appriciate your thought, wanting me to learn the "basics", but since I haven't yet had an answer to something I've tried to get in about 15 hours I don't think you're qualified to tell me to go and do this on my own. Now, if you have nothing helpful to say, please don't say anything at all. That would be appriciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you can use to throw your player is `Rigidbody.AddForce`

### Using it with an object that is a trigger:

A trigger object: [image: A trigger object] 
How can you use it? Like this:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
}
```

How to make it throw you up only if you press space?

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
}
```

### Using it with an object that isn't a trigger:

A non-trigger object: [image: Non-Trigger object] 
How can you use it? Like this:

```
private void OnCollisionStay(Collision other)
{
    other.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * 300);
}
```

How to make it throw you up only if you press space?

```
private void OnCollisionStay(Collision other)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        other.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * 300);
}
```

#### What AddForce does?

AddForce will add a force to the direction you specify

More info on AddForce: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html

Comment: Is this all the code that is needed? If I use this code I should be able to walk over an object and said object will make me jump like my space button (jump button)?

Comment: now it will make you jump if you press space. Just put it in the jump Pad and it should work

Comment: I put this on the object I wanted to walk over. I put the second one in as Chi3k3r told me to do. Nothing happened. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check the code now, use the first one for an object with a Trigger, and the second one for a non-Trigger object.

Comment: What do you mean by an object having a "trigger". Apologies, I'm fairly new to c#. I'll put both of these into object (dragging them into the object under the "add component" spot). And let you know if it worked.

Comment: Check the edit I made to my answer

Comment: First, let me inform you about my character. I took my character from the asset store so I actually don't know a lot about the coding the person did with it. Secondly, I tried both of these and it didn't seem to be working. I made a cylinder and minimized it to a platform style thing, jumped on it, stood on it for a few secs, nothing. And then I used the other code that requires me to jump, tried it, and it didn't work. I'm probably screwing this up somehow. I don't have "Is trigger" on in my platform. Should I?

Comment: Don't use "on trigger", instead try the code that doesn't require "On Trigger"

Comment: Oh, I see. So, for the one the requires "On trigger" I didn't have it on, but for the ones that required them off, I had them off and it didn't work. So what I'm going to do now is toggle on trigger and try out the two above yet again. Appriciate all of this, I really do. Thank you for trying to help me with this.

Comment: Also, make sure the character has a Rigidbody

Comment: A rigidbody, got it. I have yet to put a rigidbody in the object, that might be the problem. I'll be back when I've done so

Comment: There is some progress. I have now added a rigidbody and I used the non-trigger using script and the first one of them. I can move the object, but when i jump ontop of it for it to shoot me away, it just shakes and doesn't do anything more than that. And yes, the character has a rigidbody.